# What are the main features of an agglutinative language?

Tags: grammar, morphology

As I was beginning to study some Esperanto, it immediately became clear that the language used the same morphemes without significant modification. Therefore, on further research, concluded that it was agglutinative.

Alongside the feature of agglutinative languages having numerous affixes, are there additional properties I have overlooked? And may English be considered somewhat agglutinative or fusional?

Comment: Would this be more suitable for the linguistics stack?

Comment: English has almost no inflection, so it's neither fusional nor agglutinative, but rather analytic. The reason Esperanto has no significant paradigmatic irregularity is because it was designed that way. But modification of morphemes is not a good test for agglutination; you need to look at the paradigms.

Comment: Agglutinative languages have many one-dimensional paradigms that can be stacked together in a word, like [Turkish verb inflections](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TurkishVerbForms.pdf); fusional paradigms are usually multi-dimensional, like [Latin noun inflections](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LatinNouns.pdf).

Comment: Please make it an answer and then append to it by commenting. Plus is this not a *see Wikipedia first* question?